How to visualize attached photos inside a point layer in qgis2threejs
I have been testing the qgis2threejs plugin. It's great but I would like to know if there is a way to see the photos I have linked to a vector layer. QGIS2web allows you to do it and they are displayed perfectly. Is there any way to do it with this plugin?
